# Kubernetes NFS volume with dynamic path

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to mount my applications' logs directory to nfs dynamically including node_name.

No success so far.

I tried as below:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nfs-in-a-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: app
      image: alpine
      env:
      - name: POD_NAME
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef:
            apiVersion: v1
            fieldPath: metadata.name
      - name: NODE_NAME
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef:
            apiVersion: v1
            fieldPath: spec.nodeName
      volumeMounts:
        - name: nfs-volume
          mountPath: /var/nfs
          subPath: /$(NODE_NAME)
      command: ["/bin/sh"]
      args: ["-c", "sleep 500000"]
  volumes:
    - name: nfs-volume
      nfs:
        server: ip_adress_here
        path: /mnt/events
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of subPath you should use subPathExpr, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath-with-expanded-environment-variables).

> Use the subPathExpr field to construct subPath directory names from Downward API environment variables. This feature requires the VolumeSubpathEnvExpansion feature gate to be enabled. It is enabled by default starting with Kubernetes 1.15. The subPath and subPathExpr properties are mutually exclusive.

---

> In this example, a Pod uses subPathExpr to create a directory pod1 within the hostPath volume /var/log/pods, using the pod name from the Downward API. The host directory /var/log/pods/pod1 is mounted at /logs in the container.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod1
spec:
  containers:
  - name: container1
    env:
    - name: POD_NAME
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: metadata.name
    image: busybox
    command: [ "sh", "-c", "while [ true ]; do echo 'Hello'; sleep 10; done | tee -a /logs/hello.txt" ]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: workdir1
      mountPath: /logs
      subPathExpr: $(POD_NAME)
  restartPolicy: Never
  volumes:
  - name: workdir1
    hostPath:
      path: /var/log/pods
```

Hope that´s it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. 

Actually it seems it is correct way to do it. We tried it but as you mentioned it requires a feature gate enabled. We were not allowed to enable that feature, so we figured out creating sub directories with adding a custom script into Dockerfile. In other words, we solved this problem without kubernetes.